How do I improve my tone and flow on the guitar?
So let me get straight to the point. I've been playing for a few years, got down some basic concepts, learned some songs and solos, but I don't feel like it sounds right.
I have a Marshall MG15R amplifier, a Fender Stratocaster Vintera 50s guitar and a Fender Full Moon Distortion pedal. I've tried fiddling with it, I've tried fiddling with the amp tone, but it doesn't sound really good.
I would appreciate some tips and tricks. I usually just put everything in the middle, or fiddle around until it sounds decent, but 90% of the time, I have no idea what I am doing or how the tone is going to turn out if I turn the highs knob from 5 to 8, what if I turn it on the amp, or on the pedal? How does it work? What do I expect?
I would also appreciate some tips on improvisation, especially during solos, since I find myself getting stuck doing the same licks over and over again. I will try to shift a scale when I feel the drums and bass doing something different, but it sounds awkward there and I go back to what I was playing before - same 5 blues licks and improvisations I've always done.
Any books, tutorials, tips & tricks would be appreciated.
I am not looking to buy more gear since I have a decent reverb on the amp, a distortion pedal. Maybe I will buy a delay pedal soon, but I doubt that it will decorate the tone and awkward improvisations much.

We prefer one question at a time on this site, so could the question be split into different ones? Also, asking for books, gear, etc., is out of bounds. My simple advice would be to find a teacher (we all agree on that!) if only for a few pointers. As complete strangers who cannot hear you play, we're rather in the dark.

@Tim Problem is, between work, school and social life, I can't find the time to go to guitar lessons 3 times a week for 2 hours + transit. I used to take lessons first month or two and it greatly improved my playing. The guy was pretty flexible back then, now he is not so much, doesn't work on weekends anymore.

Three times a week?! Take one hour zoom lessons once a week, and find a teacher who fits your schedule.

@ToddWilcox When I was going to the last tutor we were doing 1 session for technique, 1 session for theory and scales, and 1 session for rhythm and solo where I would practice what I had learned from the previous 2 sessions, and it worked, learned quite a bit in a few months, plus had some take at home exercises which I could do while watching a movie, mainly for improving spreed, precision and technique.

It sounds like you don’t have time for that anymore. That’s a very intense schedule and it’s not necessary to have that many lessons if you’re too busy. Even a zoom every other week is enough to improve well from lessons. My point is you don’t have to choose between either 9 hours a week spent going to lessons or nothing. You can choose remote lessons and/or far fewer lessons and still benefit.

Those lessons should have cost a fortune!  6hrs a week, plus practice time? Waaaay too much! 45 mins a week seems to work for me. Or, as Todd says, once a fortnight. But one-to-one is what you appear to need.

There's a lot here to unpack, and I'm sure we (as experienced guitar playing performers) could write a page or two on tone.
I'll keep things simple, and advise that you seek out other local guitar players. Spend time with them. Exchange ideas, and learn their best practices.
That collaboration, in my experience, always results in an improvement in guitar playing and even tone. Especially when the other player is a really good one.
Practicing on your own becomes a very small echo chamber. It's hard to advance.
I liken it to my experiences playing tennis back in the day.
I was a pretty good player, but I found that when smacked the ball against the practice wall, I really wasn't getting anywhere.
But when I found friends and family to play with, I got better at it.
I always learned something, every time.
And more to the point, when I found tennis players who were really, really good, it made me step up my game, and I got exponentially better.

really good analogy with the tennis stuff. I had a buddy from abroad come for a practice session few months ago, and we are around the same level in terms of technique, I'd say I am even a bit better - faster and more accurate, but he went to music school when he was younger, so his solo sections were a lot more dynamic whereas mine were a bit cleaner, more precise and smoother, but it was just boring to listen to compared to what he was playing.

That's interesting, Dimitar.
I think back to the times when I hear a band in a bar or club, or when my band brings on a guest player, and I am struck by something unexpected. That "hey WOW" moment when the other guy solos.
They don't come often, but I try to listen, learn, and maybe even apply something from those moments.
